# how to open image in a box by jquery fancy box

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I want open image in fancy box window...
I tried to do this...but this is not working properly

I tried my code is bellow:

```
$('#show_dialog').click(function() {

    $.fancybox({
        type: 'inline',
        content: '#img_url'
    });
});
```

by this  i calling my fancy box window:

```
 <td class="center" style="border:#f4f4f4 1px solid; padding:10px"><a href="#" id="show_dialog" >Show Image</a></td>
    </tr>
```

this is the div whcih i want to show:

```
<div style="display:none;">
    <div id="img_url"> <img src="<?php echo $image_with_url?>" />
    <div style="background:#f4f4f4; color:#00; padding:10px;">
<p style="float:right; font-weight:bold;">Invoice No. : <?php echo $ordmaster['invoice_number'];?></p>
<p style="float:left; font-weight:bold;">Date : <?php echo getDateFormat($ordmaster['order_received_date'],1);?></p>
  </div>
  <div>
          <?php if($formPage==''){?>
          <img src="<?php echo theme_url(); ?>images/print-icon.png" alt="" style="vertical-align:middle; margin-right:5px;" /><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="print();" style="color:#1e1e1e; text-decoration:none;  font-size:12px; "><span >Print Page</span></a><?php }?></div>

    </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Are you getting any console errors?

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing content with href

```
$('#show_dialog').click(function() {

    $.fancybox({
        type: 'inline',
        href: '#img_url'
    });
});
```

There is also another way to do this

Your a tag html will be

```
<td class="center" style="border:#f4f4f4 1px solid; padding:10px"><a href="#img_url" id="show_dialog" >Show Image</a></td>
        </tr>
```

And Call your fancybox like this

```
$("a#show_dialog").fancybox({});
```